# Methods with non-type template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, non-type

I was wondering what the proper syntax to create non-type templated class methods. I've tried this, but apparently it does not work:

```
class A
{
    enum B
    {
        C = 0,
        D
    };
    template <A::B value = A::C>
    int fun();
};

template<A::B value>
int A::fun<A::B::C>()
{
    return 1;
}

template<A::B value>
int A::fun<A::B::D>()
{
    return fun<B>() + 1;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to partially specialize function templates, which is not allowed. Here is a compilable snippet:

```
class A
{
    enum B
    {
        C = 0,
        D
    };
    template <A::B value = A::C>
    int fun();
};

template<>
int A::fun<A::B::C>()
{
    return 1;
}

template<>
int A::fun<A::B::D>()
{
    return fun<B::C>() + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your specialization syntax is incorrect.  It's attempting partial specialization of a function, but that doesn't even make sense here -- and isn't allowed anyway.

You also attempt to call `fun<B>()` in the second specialization, but `B` is a typename and not a value of the enum, so the call can't be resolved.

Try this instead:

```
// Removed template argument to make a complete specialization instead of partial.
template<>
int A::fun<A::B::C>()
{
    return 1;
}

// Removed template argument to make a complete specialization instead of partial.
template<>
int A::fun<A::B::D>()
{
    // Changed template argument from B (which is a type) to C (which is a value of
    // type B.
    return fun<C>() + 1;
}
```